# FormFlow ChatBot using microsoft bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, formflow

I am trying build a chatbot using microsoft bot framework. I am building a user guided bot using formflow. I am unable to find a correct way yo build a bot where I display a different set of options for the selection. Assume the first options i provide are support,contact details and other information, when user selects I have  to display a set of options and when he selects contact details I would display another set of options, another set for other information. How would I do this?
Can anyone suggest?

```
namespace Microsoft.Bot.Sample.FormBot
{
public enum SupportOptions
{
    Specific,ErrorInformation,ContactInformation
};

[Serializable]
public class Specific
{        
    public ToolOptions? Tools;        
}

public enum ToolOptions
{
    Merge,Extend,Generate,Calculate,Memory
}

[Serializable]
public class SupportBox
{

    public SupportOptions? Sandwich;        

    public static IForm<SupportBox> BuildForm()
    {
        OnCompletionAsyncDelegate<SupportBox> processOrder = async (context, state) =>
        {
            await context.PostAsync("This is the end of the form, you would give a final confirmation, and then start the ordering process as needed.");
        };

        return new FormBuilder<SupportBox>()
                .Message("Welcome to the Support Bot!")
                .OnCompletion(processOrder)
                .Build();
    }
};
}
```

When the user first says hi to the bot, it would ask him choose between Specfic,ErrorInformation and Contact. Now, when he selects Specific support, I want to display ToolOptions.

Comment: This is a little vague.  Do you have some code written?

Comment: Added the code to the original question.

Comment: Hi @Manjunath, any updates? Do you try the approach that I shared in the reply to achieve your requirement?

Comment: Thanks a lot @FeiHan. It works. Now I am using multi dialogs to route it to different dialogs when the user selects different options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Assume the first options i provide are support,contact details and other information, when user selects I have to display a set of options and when he selects contact details I would display another set of options, another set for other information. How would I do this?

If you’d like to display `tooloption` and other field(s) conditionally, you can try to use the `SetActive` method to specify that the field should only be enabled if user selected the specific option. The following code snippet is for your reference.

```
return new FormBuilder<SupportBox>()
        .Message("Welcome to the Support Bot!")
        .Field(nameof(supportoption))
        .Field(new FieldReflector<SupportBox>(nameof(tooloption))
        .SetActive(state=>state.supportoption== SupportOptions.Specific)
        )
        .Field(new FieldReflector<SupportBox>(nameof(contactinformation))
        .SetActive(state => state.supportoption == SupportOptions.ContactInformation)
        )
        .OnCompletion(processOrder)
        .Build();
```

***Test result:***

[image]